# Application Deployment Using chef

Tags: svn, deployment, chef-infra

I'm trying to deploy application which is located on SVN repository. I tried using below:

```
subversion "SVN" do
  repository "http://xyz,/vn/abc/trunk/"
  svn_username "admin"
  svn_password "svnadmin"
  svn_provider Chef::Provider::Subversion
  revision "HEAD"
  destination "/opt/webserver/webapps"
  action :checkout
end
```

Comment: Any details on what fails ? Divination is an art, but it's rarely someone first competence on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It isn't accepting the provided credentials. and not able to download the artifacts  ..WAR files.

Comment: Add the log output, if possible in debug mode stripping beginning of run as it won't be relevant here. without the error message, just it is not accepting the credentials is quite vague